# Repost: Discord.py & Sympy(mostly discord.py I think)

Tags: discord.py, sympy

I'm trying to make a math discord bot.
I am pretty sure that my Sympy code is correct and it is just discord.py being funky.

Code:

````
@client.command()
async def solve(ctx, equation):
    x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
    k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
    f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)
    equation = equation.split("=")
    eqn = Eq(parse_expr(equation[0]), parse_expr(equation[1]))
    await ctx.send(f"```{solve(eqn)}```")
````

Please assume that I have all imports necessary.

I am getting this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command solve:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justi_zts5a0w\PycharmProjects\discord.py\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "math.py", line 42, in solve
    eqn = Eq(parse_expr(equation[0]), parse_expr(equation[1]))
  File "C:\Users\justi_zts5a0w\PycharmProjects\discord.py\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 1008, in parse_expr
return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
  File "C:\Users\justi_zts5a0w\PycharmProjects\discord.py\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 902, in eval_expr
expr = eval(
  File "<string>", line 1
Integer (2 )+Integer (3 )Symbol ('x' )
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justi_zts5a0w\PycharmProjects\discord.py\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
      File "C:\Users\justi_zts5a0w\PycharmProjects\discord.py\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\justi_zts5a0w\PycharmProjects\discord.py\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error you are getting, the problem is not from `discord.py`, it comes from `sympy`. And judging at the output of the code it has to do with the way you are introducing the parameter `equation`.

I did the following calls in SymPy Live and it outputted well:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
>>> equation = 'x+1 = 0'
>>> equation = equation.split('=')
>>> eqn = Eq(parse_expr(equation[0]), parse_expr(equation[1]))
>>> print(eqn)
Eq(x + 1, 0)
```

In your code, however, it is telling you that the `parse_expr` cannot evaluate the expression correctly due to the syntax being introduced. Make sure your input equation has a valid format.

Comment: What is the syntax for parse_expr()? I thought all you needed was a string. So I put equation = str(equation) but that didn't work.